# GUI component layout in Racket/Scheme

Tags: user-interface, scheme, racket

I am using following code for a small GUI program:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define ff (new frame%
                [label "Adjust widths"]
                [height 100]
                [width 300]))
(new message% [parent ff][label "testing"])
(new text-field% [parent ff][label "tf1"])
(new text-field% [parent ff][label "tf2- a long prompt"])
(new text-field% [parent ff][label "tf3               "])
(new text-field% [parent ff][label "tf4               "])
(send ff show #t)
```

However, I am not able to get desired layout: 
[image]

How can I get above layout. I see `text-field` and other components have min-width and stretchable-width. Which if these is default and which is actual is not clear to me. How can I fix the width of `text-field`? Should I use `table-panel` package for this? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I checked https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/windowing-overview.html?q=gui and also tried different options such as `[min-width 50]` and `[stretchable width #f]` but apparently it is not possible to fix the size of text-field to a particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to first set the labels to the one of maximum width, then change them to the desired label. This works for me at least.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define ff (new frame%
                [label "Adjust widths"]
                [height 100]
                [width 300]))
(new message% [parent ff][label "testing"])
(define strings
  '("tf1" "tf2- a long prompt" "tf3" "tf4"))
(define str-max (argmax string-length strings))
(define txt-fields
  (for/list ([str (in-list strings)])
    (new text-field% [parent ff] [label str-max])))

(for ([tf (in-list txt-fields)]
      [str (in-list strings)])
  (send tf set-label str))

(send ff show #t)
```

[image]

Since fonts may not have a fixed width, you may want to use underscores for the string of maximum length.

Another possibility is to get rid of the text-field's label altogether by passing `#f` as argument and make your own using a `message%` for which you can actually control the width with `min-width`. You may need to put the message and the text-field in a `horizontal-panel%`.